# 20+ Virtual Machines Running at Once

Tags: virtual-machine

I've managed to run around 5 VM's on my desktop at once before it froze and crashed. I'd like to be able to run 20 or more at once without having to use multiple computers.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this without breaking the bank too badly? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the software solution you are using you might want to take advantage of running your instances in headless mode. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless

Comment: Which hypervisor are you using? What kind of VMs are you intending to run? What hardware is your desktop pc composed of? Which was the bottleneck you found?

Comment: Do you really need to run entire VMs (which run full operating systems)? What's your specific use case? Can you use Docker containers instead? It would be much faster and have much lower overhead. Alternatively, if you really need that many VMs, you can run them in parallel in a public cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual machines are virtual, they are not magic. If you have 20 virtual machines running they still have to share the resources of your 1 actual desktop computer. So you could probably run more virtual machines by allocating less memory to each virtual machine, but the number of virtual machines you can operate is limited by the underlying memory/CPU resources of your computer.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find out where your bottleneck is. My best guess is memory. If your VM software supports it, try giving the virtual machines dynamic memory so that they don't allocate much that they aren't using.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answers, virtual machines do have to share the physical resources on your machine. Depending on how much money you are willing yo spend, you could upgrade your RAM or your CPU. Depending on exactly what you intend to do on these virtual machines, you might be able to get away with allocating less RAM to each one. If each of the virtual machines is running a 32 bit OS, you could probably give each one 1 GB of RAM, give or take. For 20 virtual machines running at the same time, I would recommend 32 GB of ram. If all of your VMs are 64 bit, you're going to need even more. A cheap CPU is definitely not going to do very well with that either. More cores will likely improve your performance significantly (but will be pretty hard on your wallet).

I know that this doesn't really sound like an "on a budget" solution, but aside from allocating a miniscule amount of RAM to each machine, there isn't really much else you can do. The issue here is that your hardware simply can't handle it, therefore, you need better hardware.